# Global variable in c++ error LNK2020

Tags: c++

I have a C++ aplication with one form (Form1.h) and a plugin.ccp file that is the actual application .The program is a plugin for Mach3 cnc controler which comunicates with the cnc machine by USB.

I want a global variable that can be used in Form1.h and in plugin.ccp.
A tried with a solution i found on this site.

Form1.h :

```
extern BOOL B1;
```

Form1.ccp

```
#include "Form1.h"
BOOL B1 = TRUE ;
```

plugin.ccp

```
#include "Form1.h"
```

And it compiles without errors .
But when a type something like this

Form1.h

```
B1 = FALSE;
// or 
SomeOtherVar = B1;
```

It gives me

```
Error   1   error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A00003B) "int mach_plugin::B1" (?B1@mach_plugin@@3HA) E:\mach_vmotion\Plugin.obj  mach_vmotion
Error   2   error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A00000E) "int mach_plugin::B1" (?B1@mach_plugin@@3HA) E:\mach_vmotion\Form1.obj   mach_vmotion
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int mach_plugin::B1" (?B1@mach_plugin@@3HA)  E:\mach_vmotion\Form1.obj   mach_vmotion
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int mach_plugin::B1" (?B1@mach_plugin@@3HA)  E:\mach_vmotion\Plugin.obj  mach_vmotion
Error   5   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   E:\mach_vmotion\Debug\mach_vmotion.dll  mach_vmotion
```

Comment: Sweeping generalisation: "Global variables are bad". Solve your problem by not using them.

Comment: What's `mach_plugin`? It looks like you haven't posted all the context needed in your question such as the enclosing scopes of your declarations.

Comment: How can i send data to usb with separate thread without global variable ?

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates you have something like :

```
namespace mach_plugin {
#include "form1.h"
}
```

while your B1 is defined at global scope. Make up your mind where it belongs and make the declaration in header match -- and avod including files inside any blocks, `namespace`, `extern "C"`, whatever.

Comment: Didn't even notice the scoping issue, must have had tunnel vision [or it was too early in the morning : ) ]. Still, even if that's fixed, trying to assign at file scope won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Was that directed at me or the OP?

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't try to assign to variables in header files. Whether you put these assignments before or after the `extern BOOL B1` (or deleted that line entirely), it won't work correctly. Instead, assign `B1` and `SomeOtherVar` where they're defined (either via initialization or inside a function).

Answer (score 0):

inside Form1.cpp. Try

```
#include "Form1.h"
namespace mach_plugin{
BOOL B1 = TRUE ;
}
```

You need to post more codes so that we may see it clearly.